# Why 512 behaves worse than 4096 when NVMe configured with 512 sector size?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd

I used Intel SSD data center tool to check my NVMe information, as shown below:

```
- Intel Optane(TM) SSD DC P4800X FUKS7175003R375AGN -
...
Bootloader : EB3B0213
DevicePath : /dev/nvme0n1
DeviceStatus : Healthy
Firmware : E2010211
IntelNVMe : True
LBAFormat : 0
NativeMaxLBA : 732585167
NumErrorLogPageEntries : 63
NumLBAFormats : 6
PhySpeed : The selected drive does not support this feature.
PhysicalSectorSize : The selected drive does not support this feature.
PhysicalSize : 375083606016
PowerGovernorAveragePower : The desired feature is not supported.
...
SMBusAddress : 256
SectorSize : 512
SerialNumber : FUKS7175003R375AGN
TCGSupported : False
...
```

As you can see, SectorSize = 512. However, when I test with fio using `blocksize=4096` is a lot faster than `blocksize=512`. I know that a page in SSD needs to be erased before writing again, but here 512 should be exactly the same as a page, so it should be fast, how come this happen?

Comment: ["Out of the box it emulates 512B sectors for the sake of compatibility, but using the NVMe FORMAT command it can be switched to emulate 4kB sectors.  The larger sector size reduces the amount of metadata the SSD controller has to juggle, so it usually allows for slightly higher performance"](https://www.anandtech.com/show/11209/intel-optane-ssd-dc-p4800x-review-a-deep-dive-into-3d-xpoint-enterprise-performance) - So the better performance with the larger sector size is as designed.  "how come this happen?"

Comment: @Ramhound So the reported number is an emulated number to OS and the actual physical sector size is still 4096.

Comment: The article says both 512B and 4kb are emulated, and that might be the case, but point of the article is to indicate the better performance is to be expected and to point out your assumption that the device 512B was the same size of the page was incorrect.

Comment: Using larger Blocksizes in fio will most likely result in faster transfers on almost any devices.

Comment: It takes longer to juggle more sectors around. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 5):

With SSDs, the block size presented to upper layers is nowhere near the erase page size but 4096 bytes IS closer to the erase page size than 512 bytes. Further, if you send data down in "clumps" of 4096 bytes rather than 512 bytes then everything has less work to do for the same total I/O and the I/O will be more frequently aligned to page size. In fact you will probably find things are faster again when using a 64k block size - minimum block size is different to optimal block size! See http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-2-architecture-of-an-ssd-and-benchmarking/ (especially the section about NAND-flash pages and blocks) and http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/ for details.